# UIKit / UIStoryboard Convenience Classes

Tags: ios, uikit, ios5, storyboard

> The UIKit framework provides convenience classes for accessing the
>   contents of a storyboard from your code.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSTechnologies/iPhoneOSTechnologies.html

I can find no other mention of these 'convenience classes' anywhere. Does anyone know what they might be?

Answer (score 0):

I think it just refers to [`UIStoryboard`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010909). Is there specific functionality that you need that's not there?

Comment: I'm just trying to get my head around what is going on under the hood and how I can alter it. Specifically I want to use my own subclass of UIStoryboard in the place of UIStoryboard and I'm looking into the ramifications, so if there are convenience classes with references to UIStoryboard hard-coded that will be problematic for my plans. Please see my separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900643/subclassing-uistoryboard-and-creating-main-uistoryboard-programatically